# Find the Fourier series expansion of a function.

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

A periodic function is defined by
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases} 
      t^2 & 0 \leq t \lt 2 \\
     t+4 & 2\leq t\lt 4 \\
      8 & 4\leq t 
   \end{cases}
$$
and $f(t) = f(t+4).$

How would I find the Fourier series expansion?

Comment: $f(x) = f(x+4)$ means $f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{2i \pi n x/4}$ where $c_n = ?$ (and it doesn't always converge, in general it is only a formal series, that you have to prove being convergent to $f(x)$)

Comment: By using the formula, maybe ?

Comment: Note that the definition is incoherent. For example, $f(5)=8$, but $f(1+4)=f(1)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

By parts,

$$\int t^2\sin t\,dt=-t^2\cos t+2\int t\cos t\,dt,$$
$$\int t\cos t\,dt=t\sin t-\int\sin t\,dt,$$ and similarly for the cosine.

Comment: Stupid downvote.

Comment: I'll upvote it  because I think it's just the right response to such questions.  "Here, let me announce to the world that I haven't been to lecture all semester."

Comment: @B.Goddard: don't misunderstand my post. This is a true hint, that is sufficient to carry out the whole computation.